# How do you handle error conditions with NSURLConnection in an OS X console application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, console-application

I'm seeing a situation where sometimes loading a URL fails, but it fails very "badly". When a host is unreachable (i.e. VPN not connected), it seems that `+[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:]` often hangs with the following backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  in mach_msg ()
#2  in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  in +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] ()
#6  in -[NSThread main] ()
#7  in __NSThread__main__ ()
#8  in _pthread_start ()
#9  in thread_start ()
```

I have implemented `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`, but it never gets called.

I am constructing the NSURLRequest as follows:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest = 
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                 timeoutInterval:5.0];
```

So I was assuming that rather than hanging indefinitely, the request should time out after 5 seconds. This is not happening.

I should note that this occurs within a console application for Mac OS X (it's a test framework for an iOS library). I'm wondering if something "strange" is happening with the run loop configuration. (from the trace, it looks like it might be trying to spin up a new run loop from within the run loop it's running in?!)

Any ideas?

**Edit**: Since this is not a Cocoa application, I'm having to run the run loops by hand. This seems like it's probably part of the problem.

Comment: Does this only happen when you establish a VPN connection, which at some point times out?

Comment: @Perception, the code works fine when I am connected to my VPN, as some of the URLs being loaded are only available when the VPN is active. If my VPN isn't active, I'd like it to fail gracefully, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The issue occurred because I didn't give the run loop enough time. I had some code similar to this:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:
    [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
```

This only caused the run loop to run for 5 seconds, just enough time for me to NOT get the callback from the URLConnection saying it had failed. I changed it to something more like this, and it worked:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:
    [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
```

I think the side-effect of this, seen in the backtrace, was that the URLConnection object, upon trying to make its callback, had no way to detect that the run loop had stopped, and in `mach_msg_trap` it's likely waiting for a reply it will never receive. I can't fully explain that behavior, but that's the general theory. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it seems like the timeout you've provided should kick in.  There may be a bug.

You may be able to ameliorate the issue somewhat by checking network reachability before attempting the connection.  See the [SCNetworkReachability API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html).

You can also impose a timeout of your own by installing a timer on the run loop – the one you're running on a thread you control, rather than the one the framework is running in the background – and cancelling the connection when it fires.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions. I'm not sure if SCNetworkReachability will work because the hosts may be behind an HTTP proxy server, but perhaps I can test the reachability of the proxy. I don't think I can cancel the connection because the run loop is in a "hung" state by the time I get to the backtrace I posted. No other events are firing on it. (I'm trying to distill this into a test case I can reproduce; will likely update the question if I can.)

Comment: Network reachability checks if the OS even knows a route of the computer. Does it have an interface to go out of? Which run loop is in a hung state? You posted a backtrace from a background thread which seems to be managed by the framework. It also looks idle and ready to respond. Is it your main thread's run loop (whichever you're running as you wait for the connection to do its thing) that's hung? Post the backtrace of that one.

Comment: That's just it. If I'm not VPN'd in, I'll still have a route. I just won't be able to reach the host. The backtrace I posted is from a background thread, which I started, initiated the URL connection from, and then started the run loop. I think I may be having problems because I'm not letting Cocoa set up all its default run loops, since this isn't a Cocoa application. The run loop is started in frame 6, and in frame 3 another run loop seems to have been created. I would expect the URL connection to queue tasks on the one running in frame 6, not create its own.

Comment: +1 for the effort. ;-) I believe I fixed the issue. Posting an answer shortly.